# How can I lookup the points in a VectorDrawable in runtime?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, android-vectordrawable

I have a VectorDrawable:

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:viewportHeight="1052.3622"
    android:viewportWidth="744.0945" android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#ff0000"
        android:name="group1"
        android:pathData="M182.9,349.5m-74.7,0a74.7,74.7 0,1 1,149.3 0a74.7,74.7 0,1 1,-149.3 0"
        android:strokeAlpha="1" android:strokeColor="#000000" android:strokeWidth="4.23501825"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#00ff00"
        android:name="group2"
        android:pathData="M474.3,392.4a84.3,102.9 0,1 0,168.6 0a84.3,102.9 0,1 0,-168.6 0z"
        android:strokeAlpha="1" android:strokeColor="#000000" android:strokeWidth="5"/>>
</vector>
```

At runtime I would like to know where the points in `group1` or `group2` are. Unfortunately I didn't find the function that gives me the relevant data. Is there one?

Comment: nein, mission impossible

Answer (score 0):

although you can't extract this from the VectorDrawable during runtime, what I did on my project was to extract the path data to a string resource and remembering that in a path data `M` is move, `L` is line, `C` is curve and `Z` is close, parse the string programmatically.

so I have in my string.xml

```
<string name="vector_path" translatable="false">M182.9,349.5m-74.7,0a74.7,74.7 .... etc
```

and in my vector.xml

```
<path android:pathData="@string/vector_path"
```

and on runtime you can process this `vector_path` string using `String.split` and `Float.parse`

I hope it helps